# Joining indirect associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table A with a polymorphic column that is directly or indirectly associated to table D
in three different ways.

```
A -> D
A -> B -> D
A -> C -> B -> D
```

A

| id | polymorphic_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 (for table B) |
| 2 | 6 (for table C) |
| 3 | 7 (for table D) |

Here's a simple example of the tables and relevant columns

B

| id | d_id |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 7 |

C

| id | b_id |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 5 |

D

| id |
| --- |
| 7 |

Given A, I want to get all the rows for column id from D

Is there a way I can join these all together? I think some type of UNION is what I'm looking for.

This could be a regular sql query (I'm using postgres) or in Rails 2.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana thanks just added. although I don't know why the markdown isn't working when I submit...

Comment: so what if an id exists in two tables,  for example in table A , you get polymorphic_id = 10 and id = 10 exists in both table B and D?

Comment: if you do left join table a to all other table it will work i think

Comment: EX- **select * from a left join b on b.id = a.id left join c on c.id = a.id** and so on